# re expressing the Cauchy Riemann Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
 &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}
  + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\\
 &= \frac12 \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
                -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
 \right)
\end{split}
$$

I saw the Cauchy-Riemann on wolfram alpha and am confused as to how the second equality comes about, any insight would be great!

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deduce the second equality it is sufficient to note that, since $z=x+iy$ (and $\bar{z}=x-iy$), then
$$
x=\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar z)\quad y=-\frac{i}{2}(z-\bar z)
$$
so
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\quad\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}=-\frac{i}{2}
$$

Comment: follow up here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927819/on-understanding-the-cauchy-riemann-equations