# On understanding the Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I asked this question: [re expressing the Cauchy Riemann Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927229/re-expressing-the-cauchy-riemann-equations)

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
 &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}
  + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\\
 &= \frac12 \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
                -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
 \right)
\end{split}
$$

Where I asked why the second equation holds.

and this was the awnser given:
To deduce the second equality it is sufficient to note that, since $z=x+iy$ (and $\bar{z}=x-iy$), then
$$
x=\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar z)\quad y=-\frac{i}{2}(z-\bar z)
$$
so
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\quad\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}=-\frac{i}{2}
$$

I am still confused by one thing, to me it seems that the derivative of $\bar{z}$ does not exist, we can get both 1 and -1 at a same point approaching it either by the reals or the imarginaries.

So how would one get the derivative of: $z - \bar{z}$ with respect to $z$?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that it takes place after you complexify, i.e., instead of $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, you let $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ and consider the change of coordinates from $x,y$ to $(z,\bar{z})=(x+iy,x-iy)$ as a purely algebraic manipulation (it has geometric interpretations too, but let's ignore that for now).  Then $z,\bar{z}$ are independent coordinates, so $\dfrac{\partial\bar{z}}{\partial z}=0$ (note that it is $\partial$ not $\mathrm{d}$, so there isn't much risk of confusion).